# Как развернуть проект, если в нем есть composer?

Tags: docker, composer

Как развернуть проект, если в нем есть composer?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы поднимите контейнеры командой `docker-compose up -d` выполните команду `docker exec -ti имя_контейнера_php composer install`